# grails:get list on multiple hasmany

Tags: grails, pagination, associations

How can I fetch a list (with order and pagination) from a multiple hasmany ?

For example I want the retreive the list of all Companies that have an employee named "Jean".

Example of code with two hasmany that I want to use:

```
class Company{

    String param1   

    static hasMany =  [Services:Service]

}

class Service{

    static hasMany =  [Employees:Employee]  

}

class Employee{

    String name

}
```

I know I have to use createCreatia like:

```
class getListService{

   def load(offset, max, name) {

    def idList =  ClassA.createCriteria().list (max: max, offset: offset) {
      projections { distinct ( "id" ) 
          property("date")
          property("id")
      }
      ClassBList{
                    eq("name",name)    
    }
      order("date","desc")
    }

    return idList

 } 

}
```

But this example works only with one hasmany

Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For,

*I want the retreive the list of all Companies that have an employee named "Jean"*

Have you tried?

```
def companyList = Company.createCriteria().list (max: max, offset: offset){
    services{
        employees{
            eq('name', 'Jean')
        }
    }
}
```

You can have `projections` in `Company` as per your need, I have not added that to answer.

*Note* - Lower case for associations will be less confusing and clear. Hence `services` and `employees` instead of `Services` and `Employees` respectively in the above criteria.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use list(params) on createCriteria

def  offset  // use it on you controller
def pageTotal //
def pageMax // set them on your jsp page

```
 def idList =  ClassA.createCriteria().list (params) {
      projections { distinct ( "id" ) 
          property("date")
          property("id")
      }
```

this way was my filter page works like a charm :) , any thing ping me ...for details ..